# MooTools Plugin Function for Vertical Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mootools

How would one write a plugin function (class?) in MooTools that can be called on a set of elements in order to vertical align them? I have a similar function I've used for jQuery, and it looks like this:

```
  $.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var ah = $(this).height();
      var ph = $(this).parent().height();
      var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
      $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
  };
```

I'm a bit at a loss about how one would do something similar in MooTools. Is the proper method to create a class as is suggested [here](http://www.nitinh.com/2010/01/vertical-align-middle-using-javascript-jquery-mootools/)? This does not seem to be an improvement on jQuery and something seems wrong about this approach. Does anyone know the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the info you got already from Tim Wienk on IRC and Github, here is a practical example of how the MooTools version could look like:

```
Element.implement('vAlign', function () {
    var ah = this.getSize().y;
    var ph = this.getParent().getSize().y;
    var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
    this.setStyle('margin-top', mh);
});

$$('div').vAlign();
```

**Example online: http://jsfiddle.net/bTcb8/**

Comment: Yes, thank you!! Had just implemented the same thing.